# Trying to add a new value to sql using two inner joins

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO tbluser (usr_role_temporary, usr_created_at, usr_updated_at)
VALUES ('planning', NOW(), NOW())

FROM tbluserrole A 
INNER JOIN tbluserrole B ON A.usrr_usr_id = B.usr_id
INNER JOIN tblrole C ON A.usr_role_id = C.role_id
WHERE role_planning = TRUE;
```

Hi, I'm trying to achieve something in SQL. I want to insert a new value, using two inner joins, where a certain condition is true (role_planning). Most examples speak of copying data from other tables, but I want to introduce new values in a column, where three tables meet certain criteria. Halp!

Comment: You are not inserting values from those three tables, just 3 defaults?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: @Jelie . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your question doesn't make sense.  I would expect a table called `user` to have columns such as the user id.  I think you should probably ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clearer explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want `select` statement :

```
INSERT INTO tbluser (usr_role_temporary, usr_created_at, usr_updated_at)
     SELECT 'planning', NOW(), NOW()
     FROM tbluserrole A INNER JOIN 
          tbluserrole B 
          ON A.usrr_usr_id = B.usr_id INNER JOIN 
          tblrole C 
          ON A.usr_role_id = C.role_id
     WHERE role_planning = TRUE;
```

This will generate duplicate values, if you want unique entry the use `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'planning', NOW(), NOW()
```

Comment: If they want unique entries they can just use the `values` clause, since there will only be one distinct record.